# my profile page is not adaptable with phone screen using bootstrap css and html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hi i want to make a profile page with css html and bootstrap 3, my problem here is this page is not suitable for phone, and i apologize because i am following beginner in bootstrap.and also `profile-nav` I want to be in one line.you can check here https://www.aswaktinghir.ma/users

```css
    html {
  font-family: "proxima-nova",sans-serif;
}

/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, html a {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.004);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

/* ==== */
.site-header {
  height: 44px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E1e1e1;
}

.cover-photo {
  width: 980px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;  
}

.body {
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 4;
  position: relative;
}

.left-col, .right-col {
  width: 226px;
  float: left;
  min-height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.left-col {
  margin-right: 24px;
  position: relative;
  top: -150px;
  left: 8px;
}

.center-col {
  float: left;
  width: 480px;
  margin-right: 24px;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.right-col {
  background-color: blue;
}

/* LEFT COL */
.user-info h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.2;
  padding-top: 4px;
}
.user-info h2 {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.user-info .meta {
  padding: 8px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.user-info .meta p {
  line-height: 1.6;
}
.user-info .meta i {
  font-size: 0.95em;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.profile-avatar {
  width: 218px;
  height: 218px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  background-color: #fff;
  right: 0;
}
.profile-avatar .inner {
  width: 206px;
  height: 206px;
  margin: 5px;
  
}

/* CENTER */
.image-grid {
  width: 100%;
}
.image-grid li {
  float: left;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
.image-grid.col-31 li {
  width: 32%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.image-grid.col-31 li:nth-child(3n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.image-grid.col-3 li {
  width: 32%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.image-grid.col-3 li:nth-child(3n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.profile-nav {
  height: 46px;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E1E1E1;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.profile-nav ul > li {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 44px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.profile-nav li.active {
  color: #1E1E1E;
}

.content .unit {
  padding: 8px 0 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E1E1E1;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.content .unit:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.content .unit h3 {
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  color: #777;
}
.content .unit h3 a {
  color: #1e1e1e;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.content .unit p.time {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.content .unit .more {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #777;
}
.content .unit .more a {
  color: #777;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="page-content">

   <header class="site-header"></header>

   <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="cover-photo" style="background-image: url('gallery/not-found.jpg')"></div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="body">
      <section class="left-col user-info">
            <div class="profile-avatar">
              <div class="inner" style="background-image: url('gallery/not-found.jpg')">
              </div>
            </div>
            <h1>MARZOUK NAJIB</h1>
            <h2>A propos</h2> 
            <div class="meta">
              <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-map-marker"></i>Tinghir (tihit [tihit soufla])</p>
              <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-link"></i>hay tihit tinghir</p>
              <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-link"></i>mansour tihit tinghir</p>
              <p><i class="fa fa-fw fa-clock-o"></i> Joined Dec 26, 2008</p>
            </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <section class="section center-col content">
        <nav class="profile-nav">
          <ul>
            <li>convert image</li>
            <li>Profile image</li>
            <li>my propre image</li>
            <li>my informations</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
     </section>
    </div>
    
    
     <section class="right-col">
     </section>
    
    
   </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, your issue is bascially a rookies mistake. You have elements with a declared fixed width of 980px. Thats larger then any mobile screen size (max 480px). Please read into the difference between hardware pixels (physical pixels) and viewport pixels (css pixels) for mobile devices. Then use media queries to create designs for mobile use.

Answer (score 0):

You have such errors in CSS classes, f.e. 'col-md 12' needs to be 'col-md-12' and others. You need pay attention also to your columns structure.

And for the understanding the Bootstrap CSS - you can just read non-minimized CSS and find their needed classes.